# Azure logic app read all messages from storage account queue

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How can I read all messages from Azure storage account queue? The basic "Get messages from queue" job has only the number of messages where I can specify one static number:

[image]

Can I somehow get the current message count from queue for this task? Or should I just put high enough number for number of messages?

My aim is to go through all messages in queue and check if there is one particular text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, this is not allowed, even you set a high enough number.

Cause there is a limit with the azure storage queue rest API, the number of messages to retrieve from the queue, up to a maximum of 32. You could check here [URI Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-messages#uri-parameters).

> A nonzero integer value that specifies the number of messages to
>   retrieve from the queue, up to a maximum of 32.

And there is a [remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-messages#remarks):

> If multiple messages are retrieved, each message has an associated pop
>   receipt. The maximum number of messages that may be retrieved at a
>   time is 32.

Comment: Thanks. So basically I should be fine if I set it to maximum of 32 as there should not be more messages in the queue than that.